# I have a streamlit UI. I will enter few details and submit a new request. I have to get a mail of these details stored. How can I do this?

Tags: streamlit

I have a streamlit UI which I have already created. I will enter details which includes a file and submit this new request. I have to get a mail of these details and file added in UI should be an attachment of that mail. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you post a minimal reproducible code?